# Eigenvectors of Hermitian Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

Consider the $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrix

\begin{equation}
T_n = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\bar{b} & a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 &  \bar{b} & a & b & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \bar{b} &a
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
I can calculate the eigenvalues which would be

\begin{equation}
a + 2|b| \cos \frac{k \pi}{n+1} \quad 1\le  k \le n.
\end{equation} 
This follows from simple Fourier series calculation. However, how to calculate the eigenvectors? Is there a general formula as well?

In general what happens for eigenvectors of Hermitian Toeplitz operators? Advanced help for any help/ suggestion/ references.

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices (not just the Hermitian ones) have known closed forms. See, e.g. Noschese *et al.* (2011), Tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices: properties and novel applications ([link](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf)).